# Set the value of a property when other property changes

Tags: javafx, binding

I have a class like this:

```
class SomeObject{
  public SimpleDoubleProperty Vre = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

  public SimpleDoubleProperty Vim = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

  public SimpleDoubleProperty Vabs = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

  SomeObject(){
     Label results_label = new Label();
     results_label.textProperty().bind(Vabs.asString());
  }

}
```

I want that whenever I change the properties `Vre` or `Vim`, the value of `Vabs` is updated to the module of `Vre+j*Vim` which would make the label `results_label` display the module of the complex number.

PS: For those thinking about using a complex number right away, I don' t want to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use proper [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Answer (score 3):

Just create the required binding:

```
vAbs.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> Math.sqrt(vRe.get() * vRe.get() + vIm.get() * vIm.get()),
    vRe, vIm);
```